# Simulate a longer period of time

Tags: date, pine-script

good day, I have a script that runs in 1-minute graphics, however when simulating, it only simulates for a week, how can I edit it (if it can be) to simulate more time, and so see the list of one month ago (for example)

```
strategy("Conjunto C-V", overlay=true)

lenv = input(20, minval=1, title="Tiempo StochasticV")
smoothKv = input(1, minval=1, title="SmoothK StochasticV")
smoothDv = input(1, minval=1, title="SmoothD StochasticV")
kv = sma(stoch(close, high, low, lenv), smoothKv)
dv = sma(kv, smoothDv)
//minv = input(2, minval=1, title="MinV")
maxv = input(90, minval=1, title="MaxV")

sellv = (crossover(kv, maxv))

if (sellv)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="short")
cierrev = input(6, minval=1, title="Min")
if (sellv[cierrev])
    strategy.close("short")
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Could you clarify, are there more bars (like a month of bars) before the very first trade? A user can see and use about 5k/10k bars depending on free/pro subscription. If you are using a symbol with session, like 24х7 or so, then there will be 7 * 24 * 60 = 10080 bars in a week for 1-min timeframe. So that's maximum what a user can use.

Comment: @Michel_T. thanks. I understand, it must be that.
I am using 1 minute graphics, and in the simulation, it only shows me trades made since 10-November and I needed to simulate more time.

Comment: If there are no more bars on the chart, then you can't do anything with it. The backtesting engine has only those bars that you see on the chart.